# Requesting assistance troubleshooting HTML forms/cards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on an exercise in HTML/CSS/JS. The premise is a library website. The idea is that I have a collapsable form that when deployed allows the user to enter the title of the book, the author, and page numbers. When submit is clicked it takes the user input and generates a html card on the webpage. This title card will display the user input information along with a slider to denote if it was read or not.

I have a few test cards generated in my code that creates the cards as intended, however when utilizing the html form i can not seem to get additional cards to create. I ran some tests to the console to ensure that the form is in fact capturing the user input and assigning it.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing. I have been messing with this issue for almost 2 weeks with no luck. I have a feeling that my "wires" are not connected right in the javascript. Thank you in advance.

Javascript:

```
// set up library 
let myLibrary = [];

//set up object
function Book(title, author, pages) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
}

//add object to library
function addBookToLibrary(Book){
    myLibrary.push(Book);
}

//test books
const lotr = new Book('The Fellowship of the Ring', 'J.R.R. Tolkein', '423 pages');
const ender = new Book('Enders Game', 'Orson Scott Card', '324 pages');
const martian = new Book('The Martian', 'Anthony Weir', '369 pages');


addBookToLibrary(lotr);
addBookToLibrary(ender);
addBookToLibrary(martian);

//inject html to create cards
let htmlCode = ``;


myLibrary.forEach(function(singleBookObjects){
    htmlCode = 
      htmlCode + 
      `
      <entry>
          <div>
          <h3>Title: ${singleBookObjects.title}</h3>
          <h3>Author: ${singleBookObjects.author}</h3>
          <h3>Pages: ${singleBookObjects.pages}</h3>
          <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>  
          </div>
      </entry>
      `;
  });



function newBookCard() {
    let newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.className+= 'item';

    let newp = document.createElement('p');
    newp.innerHTML = "Title";

    newdiv.appendChild(newp);
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(newdiv);
}


const addBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
addBtn.onclick = function() {
    let a = document.getElementById("bookTitle").value
    let b = document.getElementById("bookAuthor").value
    let c = document.getElementById("bookPages").value
    let newBook = new Book(a, b, c);
    
    addBookToLibrary(newBook);
    console.log(myLibrary);

    newBookCard();

    document.getElementById("bookTitle").value = ""
    document.getElementById("bookAuthor").value = ""
    document.getElementById("bookPages").value = ""
}


const bookCards = document.querySelector(".all-book-cards");
bookCards.innerHTML = htmlCode;


function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function submitForm(){
    let a = document.getElementById("bookTitle")
}


function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Library</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container" img src="images/bookShelf.jpeg">
            <div id = "titleCard"> My Library</div>
            <div class = "all-book-cards"></div>

            <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Add Book</button>
            <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
                <form action="index.html" class="form-container">
                    <h1>Add Book</h1>

                    <label for="bookTitle"><b>Title:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookTitle" type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" name="bookTitle" required>

                    <label for="bookAuthor"><b>Author:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookAuthor" type="text" placeholder="Enter Author" name="bookAuthor" required>

                    <label for="bookPages"><b>Pages:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookPages" type="text" placeholder="Enter Pages" name="bookPages" required>

                    <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn">Add</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src ="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.all-book-cards{
    width: 20em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


entry {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: groove;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
   
}

{box-sizing: border-box;}


.open-button {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    padding:16px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 23px;
    right: 28px;
    width: 90px;
}


.form-popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 9;
}

.form-container {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}


.form-container input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.form-container input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    outline: none;
}

.form-container .btn {
    background-color: #04AA6d;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.form-container .cancel {
    background-color: red;
}

.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}



/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
  }
  
  /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
  .switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  /* The slider */
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
  
  /* Rounded sliders */
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few issues with your code, but the main reason you don't see any changes in the DOM is that you try to find an element by id "main", but no such element is defined.

So step one is putting an id on the element containing your books:

`<div id="main" class="all-book-cards"></div>`

Another issue is that you change the DOM in different ways on many places in your javascript code which makes it harder to figure out what's going on. You could change the `addBookToLibrary` to actually add elements to the DOM aswell. To ensure consistency with the initial books you create in the foor loop, I have changed the addBookToLibrary to handle the entire creation and removed the for loop.

```
//add object to library
function addBookToLibrary(Book){
    myLibrary.push(Book);
    let html =  `
      <entry>
          <div>
          <h3>Title: ${Book.title}</h3>
          <h3>Author: ${Book.author}</h3>
          <h3>Pages: ${Book.pages}</h3>
          <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>  
          </div>
      </entry>
      `;
  var newEl = document.createElement("template");
  newEl.innerHTML = html.trim();
  document.getElementById('main').appendChild(newEl.content.firstChild);
}
```

Below is a CodePen for the full example.

https://codepen.io/rasm586c/pen/PoKdNdd